# Can interact only with the last graph

Tags: python, events, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm practicing tkinter and matplotlib.

I wrote this piece of code which creates an entered number of frames and in each frame a different plot is embedded. I can then go from plot to plot by switching between the created frames and turn a drawing mode on. What the drawing mode do is enable me to click on the plot and create a horizontal line on it.

But when I turn drawing mode on I can only interact with the last graph.

Any ideas why this is happening?

The piece of code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg

numberOfFrames = eval(input('Number of frames to be crated: '))

x = []
y = []

class app(Tk):

    def __init__(self):

        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('640x400')
        self.frames = []
        self.currentPage = 0

        def nextpage():

            try:
                frame = self.frames[self.currentPage+1]
                frame.tkraise()
                self.currentPage += 1
            except:
                pass

        def backpage():

            if self.currentPage == 0:
                pass
            else:

                frame = self.frames[self.currentPage-1]
                frame.tkraise()
                self.currentPage -= 1

        def DrawOn():

            def onclick(event):

                plt.hlines(event.ydata,event.xdata-0.1,event.xdata+0.1,
                       colors='r',linestyle='solid')
                canvas.show()
            fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

        for i in range(numberOfFrames):
            frame = Frame(self)
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew") 
            self.frames.append(frame)
            fig = plt.figure()

            for j in range(2):
                x.append(randint(1,10))
                y.append(randint(1,10))

            plt.plot(x,y)
            canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self.frames[i])
            canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=True)
            toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self.frames[i])
            toolbar.update()
            canvas._tkcanvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

            label = Label(self.frames[i], text='Page %d'%(i+1))
            label.pack()
            Next = Button(self.frames[i], text='Next', command = nextpage)
            Next.pack(side=LEFT)
            Back = Button(self.frames[i], text='Back', command = backpage)
            Back.pack(side=LEFT)
            Draw = Button(self.frames[i], text='Draw', command = DrawOn)
            Draw.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.frames[0].tkraise()

run = app()
run.mainloop()
```

Comment: Found a solution. I managed to solve it by creating a list of figures, a list of canvas and a list of subplots.

Comment: You should have a look at http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/CallbackConfusion#line-125
You have to be careful when creating widgets in a loop. Also you will be better off using class methods instead of nested functions. Nested functions are for simple case.
Here I would create a second class containing a frame a canvas and a subplot.

Comment: If you found a solution, you can post it as answer to your own question.

Comment: Do not use `pyplot` with embedding, see http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html and  http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk2.html

Answer (score 0):

That's the alteration I made to my code. It made possible to interact with all the embedded graphs. I'm not sure if it is the best way to do it, but it seems to work.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg

numberOfFrames = eval(input('Number of frames to be crated: '))

x = []
y = []



class app(Tk):

    def __init__(self):

        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('640x400')
        self.frames = []
        self.currentPage = 0
        self.figs = []
        self.axeslist = []
        self.canvaslist = []

        def nextpage():

            try:
                frame = self.frames[self.currentPage+1]
                frame.tkraise()
                self.currentPage += 1
            except:
                pass

        def backpage():

            if self.currentPage == 0:
                pass
            else:

                frame = self.frames[self.currentPage-1]
                frame.tkraise()
                self.currentPage -= 1

        def DrawOn():    

            def onclick(event):

                self.axeslist[self.currentPage].hlines(event.ydata,event.xdata-0.1,event.xdata+0.1,
                                                   colors='r',linestyle='solid')      
                self.canvaslist[self.currentPage].show()
                print(event.xdata,event.ydata)

            for i in self.figs:
                i.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

        for i in range(numberOfFrames):
            frame = Frame(self)
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            self.frames.append(frame)
            fig = plt.figure()
            self.figs.append(fig)
            ax = self.figs[i].add_subplot(111)
            self.axeslist.append(ax)

            for j in range(2):
                x.append(randint(1,10))
                y.append(randint(1,10))

            plt.plot(x,y)
            canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figs[i], self.frames[i])
            self.canvaslist.append(canvas1)
            self.canvaslist[i].get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=True)
            toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvaslist[i], self.frames[i])
            toolbar.update()
            self.canvaslist[i]._tkcanvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
            label = Label(self.frames[i], text='Page %d'%(i+1))
            label.pack()
            Next = Button(self.frames[i], text='Next', command = nextpage)
            Next.pack(side=LEFT)
            Back = Button(self.frames[i], text='Back', command = backpage)
            Back.pack(side=LEFT)
            Draw = Button(self.frames[i], text='Draw', command = DrawOn)
            Draw.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.frames[0].tkraise()

run = app()
run.mainloop()
```